# AVPlayer blocks Voip or webrtc in iOS

Tags: objective-c, webrtc, avplayer, voip

During a P2P video call I play an mp3 url using AVPlayer, the mp3 plays but the voice of remote and local audio is gone. 
So I need to disconnect headphone and reconnect again.

What should I do? I even use

```
NSError *error;

AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];

[session setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&error];

[session setActive:YES error:&error];
```

But still no luck. What work around should I use?

Comment: Try creating new object of AVAudioSession, don't use sharedInstance and then check.

Comment: @aBilal17 thanks, i solve this using the hints you give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try creating new object of AVAudioSession, don't use sharedInstance of AVAudioSession and then check.